# getting back key:subkey pair sorted on subkey of subkey of key. python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a JSON file

```
 {
"b0:47:bf:af:c1:42": 
 {
 "No. of visits": 10, "cities": 
    {
      "Mumbai": {"count": 5,"last_visited": "5/22/2016"},
      "Kolkata": {"count": 2,"last_visited": "5/22/2016"},
      "Amritsar":{"count": 3,"last_visited": "5/22/2016"}
     }
},
"c0:ee:fb:71:be:0d": 
 {
 "No. of visits": 24, "cities": 
 {
  "Mumbai": {"count": 2,"last_visited": "5/22/2016"},
  "Kolkata": {"count": 20,"last_visited": "5/22/2016"},
  "Amritsar":{"count": 2,"last_visited": "5/22/2016"}
 }
}
}
```

SO I was sorting on count to get max_visited city, 2nd max_visited city and so on  for each mac by this, after parsing to dictionary.

```
for mac in dic_data:
    sorted_cities = sorted(cities, key=lambda x: cities[x]['count'], reverse=True)
```

this gives me output like this.

```
['Kolkata', 'Amritsar', 'Mumbai']
['Amritsar', 'Mumbai', 'Kolkata']
```

which is fine but lets say I want to sort on "count" for whole dictionary and return all the keys for that , so that it can be accessed later. Like for this example max value of `"count"` is for `"c0:ee:fb:71:be:0d"` key `"cities"` sub key and `"Kolkata"` further sub key. so I want to store it in some structure by which I can call it later. * am trying to store it in array of array*. which I want to access later as `dic array[0][1]`. I am not sure if it can be done like this. All I need is to call the `"Kolkata"` and its `"count"` later.
 So, My output may look like

```
[["c0:ee:fb:71:be:0d","cities","Kolkata"],
 ["b0:47:bf:af:c1:42","cities","Mumbai"],
 ["b0:47:bf:af:c1:42","cities","Amritsar"],
 ["c0:ee:fb:71:be:0d","cities","Mumbai"],
 ["c0:ee:fb:71:be:0d","cities","Mumbai"],
 ["c0:ee:fb:71:be:0d","cities","Amritsar"],
 ["b0:47:bf:af:c1:42","cities","Kolkata"]]
```

Comment: What do you want your result to be? It should be either an array or a dictionary. Arrays are sorted, dictionaries are not, so I assume the former. Please update the desired result.

Comment: @phihag I want a array of which element will be `'c0:ee:fb:71:be:0d': 'Kolkata'` a key : subkey pair for which `"count"` is max second max and so on. if i am doing it in descending order.

Comment: @phihag what I want at the end is that I can access key:subkey for which count is max and second max... . I want to use that further in the code.

Comment: You can check that your result is valid at http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, That's whatever I understood from the question, specifics? Ask!

```
>>> with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
...     json_ = json.load(f)
>>> formatted_ = [[key, 'cities', city, value['cities'][city]['count']] for key, value in json_.items() for city in value['cities']]
>>> formatted_
185: [[u'b0:47:bf:af:c1:42', 'cities', u'Kolkata', 2],
 [u'b0:47:bf:af:c1:42', 'cities', u'Amritsar', 3],
 [u'b0:47:bf:af:c1:42', 'cities', u'Mumbai', 5],
 [u'c0:ee:fb:71:be:0d', 'cities', u'Kolkata', 20],
 [u'c0:ee:fb:71:be:0d', 'cities', u'Amritsar', 2],
 [u'c0:ee:fb:71:be:0d', 'cities', u'Mumbai', 2]]
>>> sorted_ = sorted(formatted_, key=lambda x: x[3])
>>> sorted_
186: [[u'b0:47:bf:af:c1:42', 'cities', u'Kolkata', 2],
 [u'c0:ee:fb:71:be:0d', 'cities', u'Amritsar', 2],
 [u'c0:ee:fb:71:be:0d', 'cities', u'Mumbai', 2],
 [u'b0:47:bf:af:c1:42', 'cities', u'Amritsar', 3],
 [u'b0:47:bf:af:c1:42', 'cities', u'Mumbai', 5],
 [u'c0:ee:fb:71:be:0d', 'cities', u'Kolkata', 20]]
>>> sorted_ = sorted(formatted_, key=lambda x: x[3], reverse=True)
>>> sorted_
187: [[u'c0:ee:fb:71:be:0d', 'cities', u'Kolkata', 20],
 [u'b0:47:bf:af:c1:42', 'cities', u'Mumbai', 5],
 [u'b0:47:bf:af:c1:42', 'cities', u'Amritsar', 3],
 [u'b0:47:bf:af:c1:42', 'cities', u'Kolkata', 2],
 [u'c0:ee:fb:71:be:0d', 'cities', u'Amritsar', 2],
 [u'c0:ee:fb:71:be:0d', 'cities', u'Mumbai', 2]]
>>> minimize_sorted_ = [item[:3] for item in sorted_]
>>> minimize_sorted_
188: [[u'c0:ee:fb:71:be:0d', 'cities', u'Kolkata'],
 [u'b0:47:bf:af:c1:42', 'cities', u'Mumbai'],
 [u'b0:47:bf:af:c1:42', 'cities', u'Amritsar'],
 [u'b0:47:bf:af:c1:42', 'cities', u'Kolkata'],
 [u'c0:ee:fb:71:be:0d', 'cities', u'Amritsar'],
 [u'c0:ee:fb:71:be:0d', 'cities', u'Mumbai']]
```